# Extracting Data from the last 3 lines regardless of the number of lines

Tags: python

I have been working with some Python imaging libraries lately and i have been getting issues extracting the text from the last three lines of a string.

Lets say I have a string

```
a = '''
Human
Dog
Cat
Banana
Apple
Orange'''
```

And i want to convert the stuff into 2 different lists, one of which has the last three lines of the string, the other of which has all the rest of the lines of the string.

```
first_items = ['Human', 'Dog', 'Cat']
last_items = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Orange']
```

How do I do this in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need your data by line, filtering out empty lines:

```
lines = list(filter(None, a.splitlines()))
```

Then, you can use Python's [list slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/2800876):

```
first = lines[:-3]
last = lines[-3:]
```

Comment: well what if there is a gap between the last 3 lines, it just pushes the gap into the list as well. Any solutions to that?

Comment: @GoodBoye I've updated the solution to filter out any empty lines

Comment: TypeError: 'filter' object is not subscriptable

Comment: i dont have any functions or variables assigned for filter. Is it because i am using python 3.6?

Comment: @GoodBoye Ah, it's a Python 3 thing.  Example updated

Comment: Wouldn't be simpler to just use [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)? i.e. `lines = a.splitlines()`

Comment: @martineau Simpler?  No.  More robust?  Yes.  `splitlines` does not filter out empty lines; it just catches more newline characters

Comment: No need for the `list()` (and probably the `filter()`), if you read the documentation you would see it returns one.

Comment: @martineau casting to a list is needed because `filter` returns an iterator in Python 3

Comment: The OP said nothing about filtering or blank lines—so you don't need to use it. It would probably be better to just use a list comprehension even if it was needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = '''Human
Dog
Cat
Banana
Apple
Orange'''

full_list = a.split('\n')

list1 = full_list[:-3]
last_items = full_list[-3:]
```

Output:

```
In [6]: list1
Out[6]: ['Human', 'Dog', 'Cat']

In [7]: last_items
Out[7]: ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Orange']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = '''
Human
Dog
Cat
Banana
Apple
Orange'''
```

`a` here is a string, so we should convert it into a list by splitting it with new-line character `\n`, and trim the leading `\n` by taking list from 1st item instead of 0th item

```
full_list = a.split('\n')[1:]
```

it will give `['Human', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Orange']`

Now top three can be extracted with `[:-3]` and last three with `[-3:]`

```
list1 = full_list[:3]  
last_items = full_list[-3:]
```

Hope it helps.